# Camel Csv read store data to sql

Tags: sql, csv, jdbc, apache-camel

I need to read CSV file and than i need to store all data in one table.

```
public static DataSource setupDataSource(String connectURI) {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/ams";
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    ds.setUsername("root");
    ds.setPassword("root");
    ds.setUrl(connectURI);
    return ds;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/ams";
    DataSource dataSource = setupDataSource(url);

    SimpleRegistry reg = new SimpleRegistry();

    reg.put("dataSource", dataSource);

    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(reg);

    String myString = " <route id=\"UserCSVToMYSQL\"  xmlns=\"http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring\">"
            + "      <from uri=\"file:/home/viral/Projects/camel/cxfJavaTest/src/csvfiles?noop=true\" />"
            + " <log loggingLevel=\"DEBUG\" message=\"${body}\"/>"
            + "      <split  streaming=\"true\">"
            + "              <tokenize token=\"\n\" />"
            + "              <unmarshal>"
            + "                      <csv/>"
            + "             </unmarshal>"
            + "     <transform> "
            + "       <simple>${body[0]}</simple> "
            + "     </transform> "
            + " <log loggingLevel=\"DEBUG\" message=\"${body}\"/>"
            + "               <to uri=\"sql:INSERT INTO user(`external_user_id`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`email`,`active`) VALUES (#,#,#,#,#)?dataSourceRef=dataSource\"/> "
            + "       </split>   " + "               </route> ";

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(myString.getBytes());
    RoutesDefinition routes = context.loadRoutesDefinition(is);
    context.addRouteDefinitions(routes.getRoutes());
    context.setTracing(true);

    context.start();

    Thread.sleep(16000);
    System.out.println("Done");
    context.stop();

}
```

you are able to see the code in which i have used

```
  + "       <transform> "
        + "       <simple>${body[0]}</simple> "
        + "     </transform> "
```

After executing this code it will store only 0 index row from csv. I need to store all raws from csv to sql table.

If any one know please provide  me solution for same.

Comment: I'd try adding another log statement before the <transform> to confirm that the <split> is doing what you expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an extra slash to properly escape the new line character in the tokenize part of the code , that is the only issue i see